# Two finger tap on UIButton

Tags: objective-c, uibutton, multi-touch

I've got a UIButton in my application called `myButton`. I'd like to react to a single finger tap and a two finger tap on the button differently. However, from what I understand `UIButton` objects are only able to detect single finger touches `touchDown`, `touchUpInside`, etc. After doing some research, it looks like I'll have to use the `touchesBegan` method and just check to see if both of the fingers are within `myButton` frame. Is there any easier way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Two thoughts:  Could you override the button to look for a gesture?  (I doubt that would be an "easier way" though.)  Also, are you sure changing the behavior of a button will make it past the app store review?

Comment: I'm not sure if it would be easier or not. And this isn't going on the app store...this is just a personal creation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is! By using [UITapGestureRecognizer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITapGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UITapGestureRecognizer) you can do something like this

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {   
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tap:)]
    tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
    [myButton addGestureRecognizer:tap];
    [tap release];
}
- (void)tap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gesture {
    NSLog(@"Tap!");
}
```

Comment: Though I think I want to use `numberOfTouchesRequired`